# a question about the path of a path-connected set in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ is path-connected . Let $x<y\in X$ and $r:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be the continuous function s.t. $r(0)=x$ and $r(1)=y$.

I would like to define $t_0$ as the largest $t\in[0,1]$ such that $r(t)\leq x$, and $t_1\in[0,1]$ as the smallest $t$ such that $r(t)\geq y$.

Is that rigorous? How do we know such $t_0$ and $t_1$ exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\big\{t\in[0,1]:r(t)\le x\big\}$ is bounded above by $1$, so it has a least upper bound $t_0$, and it’s closed, since $r$ is continuous, so it contains $t_0$. You can make a similar argument for $t_1$.